# How to remove posts from admin sidebar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering how to remove the posts section from the wordpress admin sidebar (see image below) [image: Wordpress Posts]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you will be needing to edit `functions.php` for this and add some code in that. This section of posts lies as `edit.php`

See the official wordpress codex documentation for `remove_menu_page()` function to understand better. Doc states function usage as:

```
<?php remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) ?>
```

Here `$menu_slug` is `edit.php` for post menu.

Now create your own function called `post_remove()` and add code in **functions.php** as:

```
function post_remove () 
{ 
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}
```

The next part is to hook your `post_remove()` function with a specific action which in this case is `admin_menu` to trigger this function. For that, add some more code in functions.php:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'post_remove');
```

***So in short, following is complete code that you need to add in your functions.php file:***

```
function post_remove ()      //creating functions post_remove for removing menu item
{ 
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'post_remove');   //adding action for triggering function call
```

Official documentation links

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

I hope this helps! Please do me a favor - vote up for my answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: You may also want to [remove it from the Admin Bar](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76642/remove-admin-bar-new-post-link-media-sub-menu).

Comment: Here's [why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57464/remove-posts-from-admin-but-show-a-custom-post).

Comment: But still the page can be accessed by its url /edit.php

Answer (score 12):

add this function to your functions.php

```
function remove_menu () 
{
   remove_menu_page('edit.php');
} 

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu');
```